# OpenSSL RSA decryption speed up

Tags: openssl, rsa

I am using the OpenSSL lib to RSA decrypt an 2048 bits encrypted data and I find that it will take ~1500 microseconds to do one decryption. I think it is too slow. Is there any configuration/function on the OpenSSL lib that can speed up it?

I do the test as below:

- On an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v3 @ 3.10GHz.
- Use 2048 bits.
- I encrypt an 8 bytes data first and save it as szFrom.
- Repeatedly run RSA_private_decrypt(256, szFrom, szTo, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) for 10000 times and capture the time taken.

Comment: Try using 1024 bit.

Comment: Could you please indicate the runtime that you are using it on? Are you sure that this isn't down to IO speeds? I presume the ciphertext data is just 256 bytes in size? More code would be appreciated, what you are seeing is way too slow. Please indicate the language in the tags!

Comment: Thanks Maarten Bodewes for the guidance.

Comment: So as indicated I've got an AMD Ryzen 3700X with ample cooling (so 3.6 GHz) doing some 1715.8 private key ops (signs) / second. These things are not very MT or cache bound, so the XEON's bigger cache won't help it much, if at all. It's also optimized, and measured using the `openssl speed rsa` command. You could perform the same command and return the numbers here. Note that OAEP padding might add quite a bit of overhead as well.

Comment: XEON's are particularly good at multi-threading (MT), so running multiple tests in parallel should give much more interesting numbers. Note that this is mainly useful to test the number of authentications/second. With a few hundred / s per core you should be able to handle quite a lot already.

Comment: Thanks Maarten Bodewes for the sharing.